# Using multiple ng-models in a single ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to get multiple values selected form a checkbox list generated using ng-repeat in anguler

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.ID" ng-true-value="'{{item.ID}}'" ng-false-value="''"/>{{item.Name}}
</div>
```

But what I want is to have different ng-models for different check boxes. How can I do that. Is there a way to do what ng-repeat does with out using ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular one checkbox is linked with one model, but in practice we usually want one model to store array of checked values from several checkboxes.
[Checklist-model](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) solves that task without additional code in controller. [examples](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)

Answer (score 1):

use `$index` as key

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model[$index].ID"/>{{item.Name}}
</div>
```

or use item unique id:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model[item.ID]"/>{{item.Name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day.

Comment: When I do that I get separate object with in the $scope.model. I want the data as attributes in the object